# How to access properties from dependent jar

Tags: spring-boot, properties, message

I've a core project that handles common concerns and applies aspects, called "Common ". The service projects uses this  core project for common processes.

I have to manage exception handling in "Common " and also i have to read messages from properties file in common. But services can have custom messages too.

So I put a MessageUtils in Common

```
MessageUtils.java
@Component
public class MessageUtils {
   @Autowired
   private MessageSource messageSource;

   private static MessageSourceAccessor accessor;


   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
       accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH);
   }

   public static String getMessage(String messageKey) {
       return accessor.getMessage(messageKey);
    }
```

}

In Common, I have common-messages.properties

```
 |-src/main/resources
    |--common-messages_en.properties
```

lets a service be named Service_1 that depends Common.

Service_1 also have service-messages_en.properties

```
|-src/main/resources
    |--service-messages_en.properties
```

To inject common specific configurations I've declared a Config class in common and imported it in service's Spring Boot initializer class. I also defined that "common-messages_en.properties" as Property Source in CommonConfig.

CommonConfig.java

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.common.core"})
@EntityScan({ "com.example.common.entity" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.common.dao" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:common-messages_en.properties"})
public class CommonConfig {

}
```

So, in Service_1 I've BootApp class which starts the SpringBoot app. CommonConfig is also imported there.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(CommonConfig.class)
public class BootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I call

```
MessageUtils.getMessage("someMessageKey.thatDefinedIn.Service");
```

It's ok, I can read Service's messages.

But when I want to read a common message in Service;

```
MessageUtils.getMessage("someMessageKey.thatDefinedIn.Common");
```

It gets NoSuchMessageException.

How can I merge different property files that are in different jars properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. When I initalize a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageResource while booting like that;

```
 @Bean
 public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 
   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

   messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:service-messages","classpath:common-messages");
   messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh cache once per hour
   return messageSource;
 }
```

(Supposing that default Locale is "en") I can access both common and service messages at runtime.